# Router undefined in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, redirect, angular-router

I would like to define a redirect from my login to my dashboard after a successful user verification. But when I implement "this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])" in my login component it gave me the error: 
"exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.router')"

Here is how I implemented the function:

```
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {
  contactForm: FormGroup;
  errorMsg:string = '';

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private _router: Router) {
            this._router = _router;
          }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required],
    });
    DBEventProxy.instance(); // Init Eventbus
  }

  submitForm(): void {
    DBEventProxy.instance().dbevent.login(this.contactForm['username'], this.contactForm['password'], this.loggedIn, this.failed);
  }

  loggedIn(): void {
    this._router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    console.log("success");
    DBEventProxy.instance().dbevent.register("disconnected", function (message) {
      console.log("Client disconnected: " + JSON.stringify(message));
    });
    DBEventProxy.instance().dbevent.register("status", function (message) {
      console.log("Client reconnected: " + JSON.stringify(message));
    });
    DBEventProxy.instance().dbevent.register("routeravailable", function (message) {
      console.log("Router Available: " + JSON.stringify(message));
    });
    DBEventProxy.instance().dbevent.register("routerunavailable", function (message) {
      console.log("Router Unavailable: " + JSON.stringify(message));
    });
    DBEventProxy.instance().dbevent.listen();
    DBEventProxy.instance().dbevent.send({msgtype: "dashboardready"});

  }
failed(message: string): void {
console.log("failed: " + message);


}
}
```

Hope, that someone can help me!

Update: 
Error occurs when I log in with my login information. I got my ConnectReply from the Server and the connection exists. But the redirect does not work. There are multiple errors. I will try to display those in the following:

1. EXCEPTION: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._router')
2. ORIGINAL STACKTRACE: (many documents and handleErrors in here)
3. TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._router')

Routes config:

```
export const rootRouterConfig: Routes = [
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
      { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/contact', pathMatch: 'full'}
    ];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Original answer

Remove this line from your constructor:

```
this._router = _router;
```

In TypeScript, when you declare the argument of the constructor as `public` or `private`, the class property will be set for you.

#### Update

Sounds like `this._router` is called in a context in which `this` is not what you expect. Within the `submitForm` method, try changing

```
this.loggedIn
```

to

```
()=>{this.loggedIn()}
```

Comment: @Boerne ok, please publish the full error and tell us exactly when it occurs (on component load? when you click something?)

Comment: Now the redirection works but the JSON messages from the backend cannot be read. Any ideas?

Comment: @Boerne this is a different issue. If I resolved your original "*`this._router` is undefined*" problem, please select and upvote my answer. For a different issue, you need to post a new question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
      this._router.navigate(['dashboard']);
```

n routes.

```
  export const rootRouterConfig: Routes = [

  { path: '', component: ContactComponent},
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

Comment: how you defined routes.. please post it

Comment: This has no effect on my asked question but thanks for your effort